# Reading .obj mesh file in Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opengl

I'm working on a program that takes in a [Wavefront .obj file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file) and eventually places it into OpenGL and displays the object.

Right now I'm just trying to read in a simple cube.obj file and print the contents. Its content is:

```
v -1.0 -1.0 -2.0 
v 1.0 -1.0 -2.0 
v 1.0 1.0 -2.0 
v -1.0 1.0 -2.0 
v -1.0 -1.0 -4.0 
v 1.0 -1.0 -4.0 
v 1.0 1.0 -4.0 
v -1.0 1.0 -4.0 
f 1 2 3 
f 3 4 1 
f 6 5 7 
f 5 8 7 
f 2 6 3 
f 7 3 6 
f 1 4 5 
f 4 8 5 
f 4 7 8 
f 4 3 7 
f 5 6 1 
f 6 2 1
```

I placed the cube.obj in the command-line args and did a check to see if it opened.

```
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
if(fp == NULL)
    fprintf(stderr, "cat: can't open %s\n", argv[1]);
else
    printf("works");

cin.get();
```

It's not even opening. Is there a better way to open the .obj file (as well as eventually print the contents of it?)

Comment: In C++ land, an .obj file is something that's produced by a compiler for linker input, and is in no way human-readable. You need to explain what actual file format you're trying to read.

Comment: Right now, I'm just trying to find a way to open it and read the contents of it. Upon opening the cube.obj in notepad, the data reads the following: 
v -1.0 -1.0 -2.0 
v  1.0 -1.0 -2.0
v  1.0  1.0 -2.0 
v -1.0  1.0 -2.0 

v -1.0 -1.0 -4.0 
v  1.0 -1.0 -4.0
v  1.0  1.0 -4.0 
v -1.0  1.0 -4.0 


f 1 2 3
f 3 4 1

f 6 5 7
f 5 8 7

f 2 6 3
f 7 3 6

f 1 4 5
f 4 8 5

f 4 7 8
f 4 3 7

f 5 6 1
f 6 2 1

Comment: Edit that data (with proper newlines) into your question, please, and it will make much more sense. :-]

Comment: @ildjarn Since it's for graphics, it can be assumed that the format is the one that stores geometry data, in clear text I think. Ryan Schulze: In C++ you should probably use iostreams at this level at least. Your code should work though. Check the value of argv[1]?

Comment: @ildjarn I will add newlines. What's the proper formatting in stackoverflow comments? \n?

Comment: It's not possible to add newlines in comments AFAIK, which is why editing into the question is ideal. :-]

Comment: @RyanSchulze I've edited the data into your question. Have a look at it to see how that was done. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not provided enough information here, but it seems obvious that the problem is very likely the contents of `argv[1]`.  What does the pointer at `argv[1]` point to?  Don't assume, use your debugger and look at it.  I bet it's not what you think.

You also don't consider the fact that your program may not have been launched with any arguments, meaning that `argv[1]` is reading past the end of a buffer.  This is tangential though.

EDIT:

Per your comment, you need to provide the full path of the file to `fopen`.  It should work if the file is in your running directory, but depending on your environemnt (VS is one) that may not be as simple as it sounds.

I ran a test with a file `foo.txt` in my \project\debug directory, the same directory as my executable.  It failed to open the file with a relative path, but succeeded with the full path.

However, if I simply double clicked the executable in that directory it worked.  Apparently VS is doing something behind the scenes that is changing the working directory.

To use relative paths, right click the project -> Properties -> Debugging -> Working directory.  Set that to your output folder and you should be fine.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main() {
    FILE *file;
    if(!(file = fopen("foo.txt", "r"))) {
        printf("no worky");
    }
}
```

Comment: I did a simple cout << argv[1]; and it's returning cube.obj

Comment: @RyanSchulze: I added some info on how to get this working under VS without using the full path.

Comment: It looks like mine was set to the "project" folder by default, but I was placing my cube.obj in the Debug folder. Thanks for clearing this up!